# Converting .m3u playlists from Windows for Android media players using Notepad++

Tags: android, regex, notepad++

Winamp saves playlists that are saved in same folder as the music as relative paths for Windows, but copying and pasting into Android doesn't work unless I convert it to Linux relative paths. So

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:262,Corona - Rhythm Of The Night
Unsorted\Corona - Rhythm Of The Night.mp3
#EXTINF:324,The B-52's - Love Shack
The B-52's - Love Shack.mp3
```

needs conversion to

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:262,Corona - Rhythm Of The Night
./Unsorted/Corona - Rhythm Of The Night.mp3
#EXTINF:324,The B-52's - Love Shack
./The B-52's - Love Shack.mp3
```

for VLC Player on Android to read the playlist properly.

Well, figuring out how to convert \ to / on Notepad++ without regular expressions enabled was easy enough, but I'm too new at regex to get a grip on how to even read the table of contents on its guides even though all I want to do after that is to add ./ to the start of every odd line after the first line.

Comment: Try `^(?!#)` => `./`

Comment: Do you mean to add `./` on each line that does not start with `#`? Then the solution above should work.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. It worked but added ./ to the last line (which is even numbered and blank), but for my purposes will do well enough. Now I'm going to study how come it worked. Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, if you mean to add `./` at the start of each line ending with `.mp3`,  use `^.*\.mp3$` -> `./$0`. Please update your question with a bit more concrete requirements so that the question could be answered in a straight-forward way.

Comment: Gosh, this is so much better than just staring at regex reference pages. Ok, so I see how you're thinking and it's helping to get a grip on this. The first advice was to skip all lines with # at the start. The second advice is to focus on lines ending with .mp3 which is even more applicable to the situation I provided, but here's the kicker: it's just a snippet and not all media files are going to be .mp3--some are FLAC or whatever.

The most applicable solution really is to add ./ on every odd line after the first.

Comment: Ok, try `(?:^.*\R|\G.*\R).*\R\K` => `./`

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so much. I'm going to figure out how come it worked so well. Thank you so much. Guided learning is wayyyyyyyy better than just staring at reference pages. Thank you once more, Wiktor Stribiżew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:.*\R){2}\K
```

and replace with `./`.

**Details**

- `(?:.*\R){2}` - two consecutive occurrences (`{2}`) of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`),
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding all text matched so far from the match buffer.

The replacement is `./`, i.e. it is inserted at the end of the match.

[image]

Comment: I played around with the string a bit and noticed that `(.*\R){2}\K` also seems to work fine for these purposes. I'm going back and forth between the reference page to understand how the engine is interpreting both lines. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: With `\G`, it is a bit more explicit. Actually, you are right, that will work the same for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is, open playlist in VLC for windows; then in VLC:

- [Menu] Media
- [select] {Save Playlist to File}
- [edit] {File name}
- [select] {Save as type} M3U playlist (*.m3u)
- [Enter]

Then I open in Notepad++, and do the following two search & replaces:

## 1)  Change line termination characters

- Find -- "CRLF"

  - \r\n
- Replace with {Extended} -- "LF"

  - \n
- [Select] {Search Mode} Extended
- [Select] {Replace All}

## 2)  Change/replace path separation characters

- Find -- ASCII Encoded "\"'s -- value:

  - %5C
- Replace with -- ASCII Encoded "/"'s -- value:

  - %2F
- [Select] {Search Mode} Normal
- [Select] {Replace All}

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use regular expressions for this.
Just replace "/" with "\", it's that simple.

[image]

Then, you need to specify the correct path by removing the previous android path, which may be the internal memory or SD card to match your directory tree

[image]

In the example in the image above, the playlist must be in the same directory as the songs (the folder structure) on android to work, as the player will search for the songs in the current directory symbolized by ". \"
For the playlist to work anywhere it will be run inside windows, you need to replace it with the full path, as in the image below

[image]

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I appreciate your input. 

The example that you provided appears to work in an environment with absolute paths where the beginning of the line has an address that has something to be replaced such as: 

    `\storage\...`